# How to filter by several fields, excluding the addition of duplicate matches by common properties to the array

Tags: angular, rxjs, filtering

There is an array of users There is a filtering form in which few fields and, two fields are required How to make sure that objects that already coincided earlier in other fields do not fall into the resulting array?

How to make a server request occur upon entering each character filtering occurs according to the minimum match of letters. I did filtering by the full phrase in the input field

**search.component**

```
    searchUser() {//when we fileds already filled
                    this.users = [];//clear users array
     const user: User = {//create new user:User
      firstName: this.searchForm.controls.firstNameControl.value,
      lastName: this.searchForm.controls.lastNameControl.value,
      login: this.searchForm.controls.userNameControl.value,
      email: this.searchForm.controls.emailFormControl.value,
      phoneNumber: this.searchForm.controls.phoneFormControl.value
     };
     for (var key in user) {
      if (user[key] === "") {    //check epmty data
        delete user[key];    //delete unfilled properties
       }
     }
```

> its not exactly what i need but it still work
>   these code get data from db

```
 this.userservice.searchUser().subscribe(
                        users => {
                         users.forEach(item => {
                          for (var key in item) {
                           if ( String(item[key]).toLowerCase() === String(user[key]).toLowerCase()
                           ) {
                           if (this.users.includes(item)) {
                            continue;
                           } else {
                            this.users.push(item); //add to results arrays
                           }}}});
                        });
                        }
```

**user.service.ts**

```
 export class UsersService extends BaseApi {
                     constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
                     searchUser(): Observable<User[]> {
                      return this.get(`users`);//get users array from db*
                     }
                    }
```

**DB.json**

> this array we get byservice

```
                    {
                    "users": [
                    {
                    "id": 1,
                    "role": "admin",
                    "login": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
                    "email": "admin@admin.ua",
                    "password": "12345678",
                    "firstName": "Master",//thats repeating field with values
                    "lastName": "Supername",
                    "phoneNumber": "380669734571",
                    "addressType": "Shipping address",
                    "adressHome": "Pushkin str.",
                    "city": "Berlin",
                    "country": "Germany",
                    "postalCode": "555"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 1,
                    "role": "admin",
                    "login": "ssssssss",
                    "email": "admin@admin.ua",
                    "password": "12345678",
                    "firstName": "Master",    //thats repeating field with values
                    "lastName": "ssssss",
                    "phoneNumber": "123456789",
                    "addressType": "Shipping address",
                    "adressHome": "Pushkin str.",
                    "city": "Kiev",
                    "country": "Ukraine",
                    "postalCode": "555"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 2,
                    "role": "user",
                    "login": "Burato",
                    "email": "user@user.ua",
                    "password": "123",
                    "firstName": "Ivan",
                    "lastName": "Ivanov",
                    "phoneNumber": "389506546541",
                    "addressType": "Shipping address",
                    "adressHome": "Ivanov str.",
                    "city": "Mosscow",
                    "country": "russia",
                    "postalCode": "555"`enter code here`
                     }
                    ]
                    }
```

it is advisable to do it through rxjs, so that in the subscribe method you simply declare the result, transfer all the logic to the service

Comment: why not simply take users from service and replace this.users??

Answer (score 0):

```
>make subscribe on each form control   
>key must calling like form control
>its subscrition initialize part
>create formgroup

    this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(20)
      ]),
      lastName: new FormControl("", [Validators.maxLength(20)]),
      login: new FormControl("", [Validators.maxLength(20)]),
      email: new FormControl("", [Validators.pattern(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@']+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@']+)*)|('.+'))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)]),
      phoneNumber: new FormControl("",Validators.maxLength(20),Validators.minLength(5),Validators.pattern(/^\d+$/)
      ])
    });

//conveyor subscribing need on afterViewInit,onInit,+ when after clearForm()

    Object.keys(this.searchForm.controls).forEach(key => {
       this.subscribeControls(this.searchForm.controls[key], key);
    });

//this an observable filtering

    subscribeControls(currentControl: AbstractControl, key: string) {
    currentControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(value => value !== null),
        filter(value => value.length > 2),
        debounceTime(500),
        switchMap(value =>
          this.userservice.searchUser().pipe(
            map(arrays =>
              arrays.filter(user => {
                return !(
                  user[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1
                )
                  ? false
                  : true;
              })
            )
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(arr => {
        ref: for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
          const element = arr[index];
          const same = this.users.some(e => {
            return e.id === element.id;//user needs unique _id
          });
          if (same) {
            continue ref;
          }
          this.users.push(element);
        }
        console.log(this.users);//get matches!!!!!!!!!!!
      });
  }
```